# Doing multiple POST-requests from data in array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array with data, and want to make one POST-request for each element. The call is going from a component `some.component.ts`, to a data service that we'll call `data.service.ts`. I'm running Angular `7.0.3`, and rxjs `6.3.3`

The service has a method for posting data from an array, like this one:

```
import { Observable, of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
export class DataService {
   ...
  public postDataArray(dataArray: any[]): any {
    return from(dataArray).pipe(
      mergeMap(data =>
        this.http.post(`http://example.com/myDataEndpoint`, data)
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I call the service method from my component with:

```
  this.dataService
      .postDataArray(dataArray)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
```

I've verified that the data is going correctly from the component to the service call.

My problems are

1. No requests are going out, i.e. nothing happens in the network tab
2. No errors are thrown, neither in the console nor when building.

My guess is that I've misunderstood something about the HTTPClient or Observables. I implemented the requests based on the `mergeMap` option in [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293).

Can you see what I'm missing?

Comment: Why don't you try one by one calls for each data?

Comment: I think this will help you .. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combineall.html

Comment: Your code looks just fine. See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/fromwithmergemap?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. There might be something else causing the issue in your case. If possible try replicating in stackblitz

Comment: Add logging error into `subscribe` or with `catchError`.